# Delegation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get delegation working to call a webservice using WebClient (or HttpClient for that matter). I have a MVC4 web application with a controller and a Web Api controller. I have the application set up on a remote server on the intranet, and I'm running the same application on my local computer, using IIS on both computers, with Basic Authentication.

The Web Api controller is simple, this is the code for the service:

```
[Authorize(Users="domain\\username")]
[HttpPost]
[HttpGet]
public string GetSimulationTest()
{
    return "WS successfully called";
}
```

This WS works perfectly fine from my browser or fiddler, both locally and remote.

In my home controller, I have the following method:

```
public ActionResult TestOwnWS()
{
    ContentResult res = null;
    WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;
    WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
    try
    {
        ctx = wi.Impersonate();
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        res = this.Content(wc.DownloadString("linktoWS"), "application/xml");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.Message);
        Response.End();
    }
    finally
    {
        ctx.Undo();
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Here's the problem: I get 401 Unauthorized on the wc.DownloadString() call. It doesn't even work if I use the local webservice rather than the remote one. If I however set up wc.Credentials manually using `wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials(user,pass,domain);` it works.

I used Windows Authentication before, but it still refused to work, so I read up on delegation and apparently, it should work fine if the accounts are identical on both computer (which they are) with basic authentication while Windows Authentication is more finicky.

Why does it refuse to use the default credentials, am I still getting delegation wrong? I've read msdn articles on it and I can't find what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: I came up with a workaround (as long as it's basic auth), which is to run `wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", Request.Headers["Authorization"]);`, but I would love if someone has a better way to fix this issue, since this fix forces both the client and target site to run basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

Authorize is a filter that allows certain users to access the action method.

```
WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;
```

The above code still gets the identity of the logged-in user. Impersonation is not the right way to do this. The code for impersonation requires you to login with the impersonated user, and get the Windows identity with a handle.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The best way is to use the NetworkCredentials as you have mentioned.

Comment: The reason I'm using impersonation at all is because in the MSDN pages I found on delegation, it claimed that to delegate with basic authentication, you have to impersonate. I don't want to use NetworkCredentials in the way I posted since we need to be able to control the access from AD. Authorize should be used to make sure only certain service accounts can get to it, and then clients will have to login as those service accounts when using the WS. It just makes no sense to me why manually creating a NetworkCredentials works, while DefaultCredentials do not.

Comment: Another thing of note, removing the AuthorizeAttribute has no effect. I still get 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Yes, Authorize Attribute is for the list of users or roles to access the ActionMethod. For you to impersonate, the way to do it is mentioned in the MSDN Link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. See sample code in the link.

Comment: Well, the whole point is to get the identity of the logged-in user. Since they are already logged into the application and it has their identity, I don't see why I have to ask for their username and password manually and use LogonUser like in the example.